# disable the fade effect and the 'touchability' of days in the calendar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router, jsx

I am currently using react-native-calendar library and I want to disable the fade effect and the 'touchability' of days in the calendar. I want them to be static and not clickable. Is there a way to achieve this? Please help who has worked with react-native-calendar.

Comment: it would be nice, if you share some code.

Comment: `react-native-maps`? please read [react-native-calendar library docs](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars#advanced-styling)

Comment: @JuniusL. excuse me react-native-calendar. In the docs I don’t see any property to do this. That’s why I am asking

Comment: from the link I shared, there's where you can provide your own styling.

Comment: @Junius L I don’t want to provide my own style but the calendar by default comes with touchable dates. they became blurred when clicked. I just want them not to be clicked or maybe just to not have that blurred effect. Have you been using react-native-calendar so far?

Comment: that's how you change the styling of components in react, you provide the style to overwrite the default touchable behavior.